# Can we do a groupby on one column in spark using pyspark and get list of values of other columns (raw values without an aggregation)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe where there are more than 10 columns. I would like to groupby on one of the columns in the dataframe, suppose "Column1" and get the list of all possible values in "Column1" and "Column2" corresponding to the grouped "Column1".

Is there a way to do that using pyspark groupby or any other funtion ?

Comment: Do you mean something like `collect_list`

Comment: Yes,  I wasn't getting the exact function. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `groupBy` your `Column1` and then use `agg` function to collect the values from `Column2` and `Column3`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 'r1', 1],
 [1, 'r2', 0],
 [2, 'r2', 1],
 [2, 'r1', 1],
 [3, 'r1', 1]], schema=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

df.show()

#output

#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|   1|  r1|   1|
#|   1|  r2|   0|
#|   2|  r2|   1|
#|   2|  r1|   1|
#|   3|  r1|   1|
#+----+----+----+

df.groupby(col('col1')).
agg(F.collect_list(F.struct(col('col2'), col('col3'))).
alias('merged')).show()
```

You should see the output as,

```
+----+----------------+
|col1|          merged|
+----+----------------+
|   1|[[r1,1], [r2,0]]|
|   3|        [[r1,1]]|
|   2|[[r2,1], [r1,1]]|
+----+----------------+
```